# Having difficulty grasping the idea behind cyclic difference matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

**This question was taken from MIT OCW and Gilbert Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*.**

What is a cyclic $4$ by $4$ matrix C? It will have $1$ and $-1$ in each row. Find all solutions $x=({ x }_{ 1 },{ x }_{ 2 },{ x }_{ 3 },{ x }_{ 4 })$ to $Cx=0$. The four columns of $C$ lie in a "three-dimensional hyperplane" inside four dimensional space.

Steps I took:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\quad \begin{bmatrix} { x }_{ 1 } \\ { x }_{ 2 } \\ { x }_{ 3 } \\ { x }_{ 4 } \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} { x }_{ 1 }-{ x }_{ 4 } \\ { x }_{ 2 }-{ x }_{ 1 } \\ { x }_{ 3 }-{ x }_{ 2 } \\ { x }_{ 4 }-{ x }_{ 3 } \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

My problem is that I was always to come up with this solution, but I can't seem to make any sense of it. The official answer also includes:

$$when\quad x=\begin{bmatrix} c \\ c \\ c \\ c \end{bmatrix}=any\quad constant\quad vector$$

What does this all actually mean? I want to actually understand what I did here that made this the right solution. (Other than the part I left out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one last step: $x_1 - x_4 = 0$ means $x_1 = x_4$. Similarly you may conclude that $x_1 = x_2$ and $x_2 = x_3$, that is all $x_i$ are equal to each other.